# What is a single word that describes a medical text?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that could be used to describe a medical textbook or reference text, something akin to a collection of diseases or procedures. I'm trying to find a word to use as a category name or title for these kinds of books. More archaic is probably better for this situation. e.g. "I looked up the symptoms of this particular affliction in the [text]."

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.*"  You can add these details by clicking on the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: Your best bet is probably *I looked it up in the **literature*** (in context, this will always be understood to mean authoritative texts / books *concerning the relevant subject*).

Comment: Most people would use 'medical text'.

Answer (score 1):

A **"vade mecum"** comes to mind.

> - [**"vade mecum"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vade%20mecum) - a book for ready reference, a  manual

A book, such as a guidebook, for ready reference.

Most medical guidebooks for ready reference are **"vade mecums"**

> - [**etymology**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vade+mecum) - Latin vāde mēcum, go with me : vāde, sing. imperative of vādere, to go + mē : ablative sing. of egō, I + cum, with.

Answer (score 0):

A ***treatise***.

[From **M-W**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treatise):

> a systematic exposition or argument in writing including a methodical
>   discussion of the facts and principles involved and conclusions
>   reached
>
> Example: a *treatise* on higher education

Examples specific to medicine: [a treatise on medicine](https://www.google.com/search?q=a%20treatise%20on%20medicine&tbm=bks&rct=j)

Answer (score 0):

***[Casebook](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/casebook)*** is used in medical/scientific contexts as a reference to medical cases:

> - (Medicine) a book in which records of legal or medical cases are kept.

(Collins Dictionary)